# Why is this symmetric matrix composed by two non-singular matrices positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Assume $A$ is a non-singular matrix. I have issue proving $AA^T$ is positive definite. I know it is positive semidefinite because $$ x^TAA^Tx = \left\| A^T x \right\|_2^2 \geq 0 $$ but non-singular only means $A$ doesn't have $0$ eigenvalue, while $x$ here is any real-valued vector.

Comment: as you write, $xAA^tx=0$ can happen only if $\|A^tx\|_2=0$. Now, $\|v\|_2=0$ for some vector $v$ only if $v=0$,...

Comment: Maybe it is $x^{T}AA^{T}x=(A^{T}x)(A^{T}x) .$ Because $A$ is non-singular, $Ax\ne 0,$ with $x\ne 0$ .Thus for $x\ne 0$ ,$x^{T}AA^{T}x=(A^{T}x)(A^{T}x)>0 $.

Comment: @Sam It's a bit strange that you're struggling to bridge the gap here. What is the definition of "positive definite" that you're thinking of?

Comment: @fusheng You're missing the middle $T$ in $(A^T)^T(A^Tx)$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I guess I'm confused because when I get to $A^Tx=0$, I then think of it as $A^Tx = 0 x$ doesn't hold only when x is a eigenvector of A^T, but when x is any real vector I don't know how to make use of non-singularity. 'positive definite' to me simply means $x^TMx >0$ for all real x except zero vector.

Comment: @fusheng I understand that when A is non-singular, $A^Tx \neq 0$ if $x$ is a eigenvector of $A^T$, since $A^T$ doesn't have $0$ as its eigenvalue. How to get it is also true for any real non-zero vector $x$?

Comment: @Sam You seem to have some misunderstanding about what non-singular means. If $A$ is non-singular and $x$ is non-zero, then $Ax \neq 0$. There is no statement here that holds "only when $x$ is an eigenvector".

Comment: @BenGrossmann sorry this seems like a really simple result, but I have trouble to get it from $A^{-1}$ exist..

Comment: @Sam "$A$ is non-singular" means that $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140550/discussion-between-sam-and-ben-grossmann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix $M$ is said to be positive definite if

$$\langle x,Mx\rangle \geq 0, \quad\langle x,Mx\rangle=0 \iff x=0$$

Notice that your matrix $M=AA^T$ is symmetric: $M^T=(AA^T)^T=AA^T=M$, then

$$\langle x, AA^T x \rangle= \langle x, A^TA x \rangle=\langle Ax, A x \rangle=||Ax||_2^2 \geq 0,$$

since $||\cdot||_2$ is a norm $||Ax||_2=0\implies Ax=0$, but $A$ is invertible, so this is possibile only when $x=0$.

Comment: sorry but '$A$ is invertible means $Ax=0$ only when $x=0$' is where im stuck at. if $x$ is a eigenvector this is true because if $A$ is non singular, then det(A) is not zero, meaning that the product of A's eigenvector is non-zero, which means A cannot have $0$ as its eigenvalue. Here I think of $Ax=0$ as $Ax = 0 x$. How to show it is still true when x is not a eigenvector?

Comment: never mind I think since $Ax=0$ always imples $Ax=0x$ this proof works for any $x$

Comment: $\langle x,AA^Tx\rangle \neq \langle x,A^TAx\rangle$